# Do I necessarily have to use conditional probability here?

Tags: probability

There are $9$ girls and $10$ boys. I write names of all on slips of paper and put them in an urn. On the first day, I randomly pick out a slip and that student is the Class Representative for the day. Then that slip of paper is discarded. On the second day, I randomly pick out another slip and then, that student is Representative for the day. Since I discard the slips once I have picked them, no student can be a Representative more than once, till all the slips are exhausted.

**If the first selection made is a boy, find the probability that the second selection is a girl.**

Now, this problem is stated in words that clearly demand use of Conditional Probability. However, I thought of it this way:

Since I had selected a boy the previous day, that selection shouldn't matter the next day's selection. On the second day, I am left with $9$ girls and $9$ boys to pick from as the Representative. Out of them, I have to pick a girl. That gives me probability of $\frac{9}{18}=\frac12$

Am I thinking correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is correct. Lets verify this using conditional probability. Let $G_2$ = "second selection is a girl" and $B_1$ = "first selection is a boy". Then
$$\mathbb{P}(G_2|B_1) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(G_2 \cap B_1)}{\mathbb{P}(B_1)}$$

Now the only way the event $G_2\cap B_1$ can occur is if the first selection is a boy and the second selection is a girl. So if you draw a probability tree you will get the result $$\frac{\frac{10}{19}\times\frac{9}{18}}{\frac{10}{19}} = \frac{9}{18}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: So we are, in fact, saying that $G_2$ and $B_1$ are independent, right?

Comment: @Tejas No, because $G_2$ and $B_1$ are independent iff $\mathbb{P}(G_2 \cap B_1) = \mathbb{P}(G_2)\mathbb{P}(B_1)$. But if you draw a tree diagram you see that $\mathbb{P}(G_2)\mathbb{P}(B_1) = \frac{9}{19}\times\frac{10}{19} = \frac{90}{361} \neq \mathbb{P}(G_2 \cap B_1) = \frac{5}{19}$

Comment: @Tejas, No. They are not independent. $$\mathbb P(B_1)\cdot\mathbb P(G_2) = \tfrac {10}{19}\cdot\tfrac{9}{\color{red}{19}} \neq \mathbb P(B_1\cap G_2) = \tfrac {10}{19}\cdot\tfrac{9}{\color{red}{18}}$$ Alternatively, the condition of whether or not a boy is picked on the first day decidedly affects the probability of a girl being picked on the second day.  How can having one less competitor on either 'side' not influence the odds?

Comment: Oh, right. I did not notice that we have $18$ in the denominator instead of $19$. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The question was "Do I **necessarily** have to use conditional probability here?", which I interpret as whether it is necessary to **explicitly** use Bayes' formula.

The answer is *no*, the way you solved it using the reduced # of children is just fine !

You don't need to use a cannon to shoot a fly !

Answer (score 0):

I understand the question as you do.

Since on first day it has been a boy, what is the probability that class representative is a girl on the second day?